# Translate query to Laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How would I translate the following query into a format that `Laravel` can parse?

`select posts.id,title from posts,albums where posts.id != albums.post_id`

Now it has this ORM relations

a Post hasOne Album
an Album Belongs to a Post

So with this statement I want to know which Posts dont have Albums binded.

so far I have

Post::with('album')->select('id', 'title')->get();

I don't know how to declare the condition

Comment: Reworded the question to express the underlying question more directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do read docs again, I think you may look for polymorphic relationship or One to Many. If you use Eloquent ORM do use relationships its the biggest why "YES".

As for the query you can do http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

There is an example in a link just fill in your query and you are done.